# Does $g_n \rightarrow 0$ converge weakly?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

This is where I am stuck while solving another problem.

Let $T:L^1 \rightarrow X$ be an operator such that $T|_{L^2(\mu)}$ is compact.

Suppose $f_n$ be a sequence in $L^1$ such that $f_n \rightarrow 0$ weakly. Then set $g_n=f_n\mathbb{1}_{A_n}$ where $A_n=\{x : |f_n(x)|<M\}$ for some fixed $M$.

Then how can we say that $\|Tg_n\| \rightarrow 0$ in norm?

It would be very nice if we could say $g_n \rightarrow 0$ weakly.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: $L^1$ on what measure space? And what is $X?$ And is $T$ linear?

Comment: @zhw, Sorry. $L^1(\mu$) with $\mu$ probability measure, $X$ is a Banach space and $T$ is linear.

Comment: @mathworker21, Why? Could you explain?

Comment: @Topology nevermind, sorry.

Comment: @mathworker21, do you have any idea how to proceed?

Comment: @Topology An example to keep in mind is $\mathbb{N}$ with the counting measure and $f_n = 1_{n}$. Then $f_n \to 0$ weakly and $g_n = f_n$ for each $n$, as long as $M > 1$. So if $T$ is the identity, the result is false. You need to use compactness of $T$.

Comment: @mathworker21, I wish to have $g_n$ a weakly null sequence. But I don't know how to prove that?

Comment: @Topology why would that help?

Comment: @mathworker21, I think compact operator takes weakly null sequences to norm null sequence.

Comment: @mathworker21, Do you have some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that $T|_{L^2(\mu)}$ is compact as an operator from the Hilbert space $L^2(\mu)$.

As Topology has pointed out in a comment, it suffices to prove that $g_n\to 0$ weakly in $L^2(\mu)$, since compact operators maps weakly convergent sequences to norm convergent ones. Then sequence $(T g_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is weakly convergent to $0$ and norm convergent, so it is norm convergent to $0$.

First, observe that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $g_n\in L^2(\mu)$:

$\|g_n\|_2^2=\int |f_n|^2 \chi_{A_n} d\mu\le M^2<+\infty.$

Now, take any $g\in L^2(\mu)$. We want to prove $\langle g| g_n\rangle\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$. Take any $\epsilon>0$. There exists $g'\in L^2(\mu)\cap L^{\infty}(\mu)$ such that $\|g-g'\|_2\le \epsilon$. Take $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\int |g' f_n| d\mu\le\epsilon$ for $n>n_0$. Such $n_0$ exists due to weak convergence $f_n\to 0$ in $L^1(\mu)$. We have

$|\langle g|g_n \rangle|\le \int |(g-g') g_n| d \mu+\int |g' g_n|d \mu\le \|g-g'\|_2 \bigl(\int |f_n|^2 \chi_{A_n} d\mu\bigr)^{\frac{1}{2}} +\epsilon\le (M+1) \epsilon$

for every $n>n_0$ which finishes the proof.